# How can I write custom rails validations on a text field where I typecast this field using another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, validation

I have a series of hard-coded questions in my app which I load via YAML:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :next_question_id_yes, :question_text, :answer_type, presence: true
belongs_to :sale_qualifier

if Question.first.blank?
    File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/questions.yml", 'r') do |file|
       YAML::load(file).each do |record|
          Question.create(record)
       end
    end
 end
end
```

An example of one of the questions is as follows:

```
- id: 1
 question_text: Does this company need to buy your products or services?
 answer_type: Boolean
 next_question_id_yes: 2
 next_question_id_no: 4
```

This is to behave as a state machine - so I intend to use a SaleQualifier model to tie the hard-coded question against an answer, and the `answer_type` field will be used to define the custom validation on the answer model before I can save it:

```
class SaleQualifier < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :questions
 has_many :answers
end
```

Answer.rb:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :answer_text, presence: true
 belongs_to :sale_qualifier
end
```

At the moment the only validation I can perform is to check that an answer has been put into the `answer_text` field (which is on a Postgres DB with the type "text").

What I want to do is use the SaleQualifier Controller to create a new SaleQualifier with the correct question (let's just assume that is question one for simplicity), and to build a new Answer instance. I know I can use the answer_type field from the Question model to determine the HTML I display (e.g. Textarea for a text datatype, radio button for a yes/no answer etc), but how can I use the `answer_type` field in my Question model to force the Answer model to run custom validations that ensure whatever data my user has entered for the `answer_text` field matches the `answer_type` for it's question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the answer_text is text in database, how about doing a format validation here?

```
TYPE_REGEX = {
  'Boolean' => /^(true|false)$/,
  'Integer' => /^[\+-]?\d+$/,
  '...' => '...'
}

validate :check_answer_text_type

def check_answer_text_type
  unless answer_text.match(TYPE_REGEX[answer_type])
    self.errors.add(:answer_type, 'invalid format')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Hoang, I knew there was probably an efficient way of doing this, but didn't know what. I'll implement your answer.

Comment: Hoang - do you know how I could get this to work for Datetime fields? The REGEX for these looks pretty horrible.